Name of extended quadratic forms
Anywhere I look, a quadratic form is $\vec x^TA\vec x$, with $A^T=A$, which was fine for be until about a week ago.
Now translating $\vec x$ by $\vec z$ results in something extended as $\vec x^TA\vec x+\vec b^T\vec x+a$ which looks to me good enough to be called a quadratic form, too, but doesn't match the exact definition, for the additional linear and constant part.
Is this still called a quadratic form, especially if $A=0$, or does it have a name of its own?

"[adjective] form" means that every term is of type [adjective].  So each term in a quadratic form is quadratic.

What you have is the most general "polynomial of degree 2" in the variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. "Form" is a synonym of "homogeneous polynomial". Yours is not necessarily homogeneous.

if it is not homogeneous, don't call it a form. Sometimes the above is called a quadratic polynomial...this fits  well with the dimension 1 case  where we call $a x^2 + bx + c$  a "quadratic"

@GiuseppeNegro "polynomial of degree 2" was far too obvious so that I didn't even  think of it! Accidentally, from where the question arises, I don't need the constant $a$.

If $A=0$ in your second case, you don't end up with a quadratic function as all $x^2_i$ will vanish. For a single variable, $ax^2+bx+c$, you need $a\neq 0$.

Will has a good point: "Quadratic polynomial" can be better than "degree 2 polynomial". You don't need to write a number in a definition, which you may find ugly. But it still leaves no doubt at all in the reader and it is also clear that it needs not be homogeneous.

The most general quadratic form I have seen is :
\begin{equation*}
(x+\mu)^T A (x+\mu) + c
\end{equation*}
Here $x$, $c$, and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix.
When you think about it as a function, usually $x$ is the variable and all others are constants.
If you start with $x^TAx + b^Tx$, then you can complete the square to get :
\begin{equation*}
x^TAx + b^Tx = (x+\mu)^TA(x+\mu)-\mu^TA\mu
\end{equation*}
Here $\mu = (A+A^T)^{-1}b$. So it is indeed a quadratic form.

Not in all cases. Let $A=0$ but $\vec b\neq 0$.

Let us do it for nonsingular $A$ then. That is usually the case. Indeed, if $A$ is singular, it should not be called quadratic form as it does not even work for $n=1$.

You could call this a "bi-affine form", analogous to a bilinear form.
Given an affine space $\mathcal A$ over a $\mathbb K$-vector space $V$, an affine form is a map $\varphi : \mathcal A \to \mathbb K$ such that
$$
  \varphi(x) - \varphi(y) = \varphi'(x-y)
$$ for some linear $\varphi' : V \to V$ and all points $x,y$, where $x-y\in V$ is the vector from $x$ to $y$.
The space of all affine forms $\mathcal A^*$ is a vector space, and just like a bilinear form is a linear map $V \to V^*$ we can define a bi-affine form via an affine map $\psi : \mathcal A \to \mathcal A^*$. If we choose an origin $o \in \mathcal A$ and use primes to denote associated linear transformations, then for any $x,y\in \mathcal A$ we can write
$$
  \psi(x)(y) = \psi(o)(y) + \psi'(x-o)(y) = \psi(o)(o) + \psi(o)'(y-o) + \psi'(x-o)(o) + \psi'(x-o)'(y-o).
$$
What have here is a scalar $\psi(o)(o)$, a linear form $\psi(o)'({-})$ on $V$, and a bilinear form $\psi'({-})'({-})$ on $V$. These correspond to your $a$, $b$, and $A$, respectively.
More specifically, your map is $x \mapsto \psi(x)(x)$, which I suppose would be fair to call an "affine quadratic form".
